# How get portion of query for use in RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to check if file exists on srver from part of a string?

I have an url like:

```
http://domain.com/faq.html
```

And I would like to check if file

```
controllers/faq.php
```

exists before doing a rewrite.

Is it possible to get "faq" part into $2 (for example) and do a

```
RewriteCond /controllers/$2\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html index.php?controller=$1
```

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close to actual solution. You can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/controllers/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

You need to provide full filesystem path using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` for checking existence of `$2.php`

Comment: One thing i dont understand... when/where is value of $2 defined? When it's assigned with "faq" for example

Comment: Sorry it should be `$1` (fixed it). It is captured in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Somehow I had a hunch it's like that.... but didn't want to belive it. So it seems first whole statement is compiled, variables are assigned and then its evaluated.... strange, but now i know what I can do !! Gonna test it! Thx.

Comment: This is strange. WHen I do
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/controllers/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ index.php?lang=en&module=$1 [L,R=301]
I get redirected to domain/%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}index.php?lang=en&module=faq